# Firebase Hosting – Cannot rewrite default traffic to anything else but index.html

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a couple of firebase hosted sites pointing to the same directory.

For this particular instance I would like a specific site to use a different default index than the public folder's index.html file.

I've set the sub-site firebase hosting deployment to something similar to this:

```
{
    "target": "subsite",
    "public": "hosting/public_mysite",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/about",
        "destination": "/subsite/about.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/reviews",
        "destination": "/subsite/reviews.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/subsite/home.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

On the sub-site, the urls /about and /reviews do indeed load the requested alternative pages listed in rewrites section.

The last rule `"source": "**"` seems to be completely ignored and firebase loads the /index.html anyway.

Why is it not loading `/subsite/home.html` instead?

The file is definitely there with the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Priority order of Hosting responses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order).

1. Reserved namespaces that begin with a `/__/*` path segment
2. Configured redirects
3. Exact-match static content
4. Configured rewrites
5. Custom 404 page
6. Default 404 page

Visiting `/` will prioritize the root `index.html` before matching against any `rewrites`. If you want to render a different resource you'll have to deploy without the root index.html.

Comment: oh, right I see.. so it's hitting rule 3 before 4

Comment: @Ben just for index.html afaik